# What’s the right NOC code for this position?

Tags: canada, express-entry, skilled-migration

I’m having a hard time deciding between either NOC53100 or NOC64320 for my position.

I have attached the job description specified in the offer letter, but it sounds a bit generic.

This will be my second season, and I do have a good understanding of my duties which are as follows:

- Running 2 hour guided hikes
- Interpreting the historical significance of the place(gold rush history, indigenous population)
- Interpreting the biodiversity of the place
- Interpreting the geological significance of the place
- Assisting with special events.

[image]